# trouble importing folder in python in sublime-text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, python-import, sublimerepl

I am using sublime-text 2 for python and wanted to import a folder as a module. I put an `__init__.py` inside the folder with contents as:

```
__all__=["imsave2","model_io","load_data","utils"];
```

where `"imsave2","model_io","load_data","utils"` are `.py` files inside the folder.
This arrangement works when using the python shell. To make the folder importable in sublime-text -2 I edited `user settings` by adding:

```
"default_extend_env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH": "/home/abc/vision/Datasets:/home/abc/vision/code"
},
"env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH": "/home/abc/vision/Datasets:/home/abc/vision/code"
},
```

where the folder/module I want to import is `/home/abc/vision/code/module1` . However sublime-text2 still can't see my module.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with sublime text and python modules. In my case it worked as follow:
In terminal, install your python module, pycountry in my case

```bash
install pip module
```

After that install in Sublime Text the python you are running. As default it is in Automatic. Install the python you are running and select in

> 'Tools -> Command Palete -> Package Control: Install Package'

Once I did pycountry module works!